# Proper caching - How should the number of results to a query be saved?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Lets say I have three normalized tables, one for threads, one for comments, and one that connects the two.

I want to display the number of comments in a thread, and that involves finding every comment belonging to a certain thread.

Obviously, I don't want to do this query every time i display a page, so I need to cache the number of comments to a thread. My two options (as I see it) are:

1. Add a number_comments row to the threads table, and update it whenever adding / removing a comment.
2. Cache the value in memory, either by telling mysql to cache it or using something like APC / memchached

What are the pro's / con's of each?

I'm thinking the first one is simple, a bit less performance but you have redundancy and storage is a lot cheaper than memory, though it does muck up the database with a "dynamic", ever changing value (also note that I'll need to save "upvotes" for comments, so this question applys to more than one "dynamic" value).

The second one is better performance, but it introduces a new technology that you have to tie in just to cache the number of things.

This project would have a relatively low amount of users, but I want to know which is preferable to a highly visited site as well (e.g. how does facebook store number of comments [I'm guessing both database and in memory]).

Comment: *Obviously*? why not its the most commonly used approach. probably 99% of sites do a db query on every page visit.

Comment: Running the query every time should be easy and fast as long as your indexes are set up correctly.  If there is additional complexity I'm missing I would suggest setting up a view table would be easier than trying to manage a dynamic field

Comment: I have a hard time believing not caching this is the proper way. It might be easier, sure, but if I have to display a list of 25, 50 or 100 threads, and check the comments each one has every visit, that adds A LOT of unnecessary load.

Comment: asking how facebook, does it so you can do it that way is like asking how NASA builds the space-shuttle, so you can build your skateboard that way.

Comment: believe or not, download a few dozen common forum scripts and check for your self.

Comment: These comments are veering off course to a "cache or no cache" debate. I've decided to cache, and am only asking how I should do it.

Comment: it's free help, if you want to dictate how you're helped - pay for it.

Comment: @Dagon Just because something is widely used does not mean it's the correct answer.

Comment: but it does kind of add weight to the argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind this quote from Donald Knuth:

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

I think caching, or "database denormalization" in this case, is a perfectly valid option, but it's an option that is best considered when the "normal" approaches are no longer adequate.

You say that you "obviously" don't want to run an extra query to grab the comment count on every page view, but it's actually not that obvious. If your database is properly configured, you should already have an index on the `thread_id` field in your comments table (or whatever you happen to call the field). Running a query based on an indexed field, particularly when the query only returns the a generated `COUNT()` field rather than a huge list of threads, doesn't actually have a lot of overhead. I think it's easier to just run that query and be done with it.

That said, there is value in denormalizing a database when performance reasons demand it. In that case, I would add a `comments_count` field to the thread table which is incremented whenever a new record is added or deleted from the table. You need to remember to add extra code surrounding your `INSERT` and `DELETE` queries, and possibly to `UPDATE` queries as well, ŀŀdepending on if your `comments` table keeps track of active/deleted states.

Again, this is a premature optimization in most cases. The question you need to ask yourself is, "is this site so busy/under such heavy load that the added complexity of managing a computed field is less costly than just running a quick `COUNT()` query?" If it is, then by all means go for the denormalization route, but it probably shouldn't be the first option you go for.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding a number_comments field is not the way to go. For one, keeping this up to date is a pain and requires extra code. It also adds redundancy to your database.

This leaves us with two options. Either you can perform a query at the top of the page which grabs the count for each id (this should be possible in one query - not one for each thread). This is simple and shouldn't be too slow.

If you're sure that performance is/will be an issue and that this is the bottleneck then APC and Memcache are both good choices. While this does add a new technology setting this up in PHP is pretty straightforward and it means that caching other items in the future is simpler.